# Combine Func<Foo, object> and Action<object>

Tags: c#, .net, delegates

I have a `Func<Foo, object>` and `Action<object>` and would like to combine these into `Action<Foo>`, which combines my Func and Action into one Action where the result of the Func is passed to the Action. Is there a straightforward way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most general method I can think of would be something like this:

```
Action<T1> Combine<T1, T2>(Func<T1, T2> func, Action<T2> action)
{
    return x => action(func(x));
}
```

*Usage:*

```
Func<Foo, object> func = x => x;
Action<object> action = Console.WriteLine;

Action<Foo> result = Combine(func, action);

result(new Foo());
```